# Syntaxic differences in calling stimulus controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

These syntassi are found across various stimulus controllers

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

import { Application } from "stimulus";

import { application } from "controllers/application"
```

Why would one invoke the application instead of the controller?

And why the difference in upper/lower case use?

Comment: *"Why would one invoke the application instead of the controller?"* well the `Application` class is [Here](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/blob/main/src/core/application.ts) and the `Controller` class is [Here](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/blob/main/src/core/controller.ts) and they provide different functionality.

Comment: *"And why the difference in upper/lower case use?"* `import { application } from "controllers/application"` imports the `application` constant from [Here](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails/blob/main/lib/install/app/javascript/controllers/application.js) which is an instance of the `Application` and differs from the the `Application` class

Comment: As far as what this `import` declaration does you can read more about that [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: These comments are most useful.   Interesting find: application.ts has `import { Controller, ControllerConstructor } from "./controller"` and controller.ts has this `import { Application } from "./application"` thus they are cross-referencing themselves.  Am I mistaken in assuming that both syntassi will end up accessing the same functions?